# Python abilities on strings

Tags: python, strings

> the Encoding scheme is given below:
>
> Don't replace the characters in the even places. Replace the characters in the odd places by their place numbers . and if they exceed 'z', then again they will start from 'a'.
>
> example: for a message "hello" would be "ieolt" and for message "maya" would be "naba"
>
> how many lines of code [minimum] do we have to write in order to encode a lengthy string in ***python*** in the above format.?

mycode is given below:

```
def encode(msg):
    encoded_message = ""
    letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    index_of_msg = 0
    for char in msg.lower():
        if char.isalpha():
            if index_of_msg%2 == 0 :          
                encoded_message += letters[((letters.rfind(char) )+ (index_of_msg+1))%26]  # changed msg.rfind(char) to index_of_msg
            else:
                encoded_message += char
        else:
            encoded_message += char
        index_of_msg +=1
    return encoded_message
```

Comment: The examples seem strange, by the way. Does "replace by their place number" mean "replace by the letter corresponding to their place number?". And if yes, for ``hello``, shouldn't the first letter be replaced by ``a`` (place == 1)? **Edit:** oh, I get it, you *add* the place number to the letter.

Comment: @Bogdan in `hello` as h is in odd place ie 1 thus, it moved by its place number 1 ie h+1 = i
Sorry if my actual question confused you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a one liner for you (since the question asks for the minimum number of lines):

```
encode = lambda s: "".join([(c if (i+1) % 2 == 0 else chr(ord('a') + (ord(c) - ord('a') + i + 1) % 26)) for i, c in enumerate(s)])
```

Comment: thnx fr tht @Bogdan?

Comment: What if i have to get input from a file and output the enocoded string to another file?

Comment: @Sandeep: um, you would write another function that opens the file and reads its contents? The initial question did not say anything about files, and, in any case, the encoding function should not concern itself with file operations (easier to grasp, easier to test etc).

Comment: yes its perfectly okay for me with out files, but im just curious about it.
anyway thanks for one liner @Bogdan